# 'Loading' div before the entire website is loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there any way to show a LOADING DIV while all the files (images,scripts,js files) are loaded?

Actually i think it can be done with jQuery/AJAX but I'm not sure cause i didn't found any solution yet.

A good example would be Google Adwords (for those of you who have an account there).

My script has a lot of images and js files and some of them are pretty heavy if you ask me so i would like to show something to the user while everything loads.

NOTE: I don't think that SetTimeout is the perfect solution cause it's not really doing the job - it only simulate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has several methods that can handle this.  I think the easiest way would be to create a `<div id="loading">` and use a high `z-index` to cover your page.  Then, use

```
 $(window).load(function() { 
     $('#loading').hide(); 
 });
```

to hide it when the document is completely loaded.

Note: This will not necessarily wait until all javascript methods have finished processing.  It will trigger after images, JS files, etc are received from the server.  However, if you have a heavy JS method that processes the page (e.g. wraps every word in a div and then does a complex algorithm on this), then you need to insert a callback at the end of that method that hides the loading dialog.

Comment: Firstly it looks like something that works but for some weird reason it doesn't some suggestions?

Comment: Weird - try `$(window).load()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the following method: place 2 divs: one container and one loading div. The loading div should have position:fixed in the css and made so it occupies 100% width and height.

On load, I would add:

```
$("#container").load(url, myFunction);
```

where "url" is a path to an HTML *fragment* (not a complete page) that should be injected into the container div. myFunction is a function pointer that should contain something like this:

```
$("#loading").fadeOut(500);
```

Which fades out the loading div for 500 ms.

Make sure you call $(document).load() instead of $(document).ready(), since ready will fire before images are loaded.